# Android:FaceBook Authorize Login Failed: The Server failed to communicate Try Again

Tags: android, facebook

Hello I have tried this many different ways and have followed the tutorial at

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

I am running windows 7 64bit and I have downloaded Cygwin and inputed

```
$ keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\manley85\.android\
debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 -a -e


Enter keystore password:  android
```

I use the sam alias `(androiddebugkey)` when I sign and export the package. The keystore is pointed to where the default location of the keystore I use:

```
"C:\Users\manley85\.android\debug.keystore"
```

after I sign and export I take the key hash that is outputed and input in my Developers page on FB in `Mobile and Devices/Settings/Key hash`

The problem that I am having is that before when I was doing everything wrong I believe it was saying "invaid-key" so I've been doing this way which I believe is correct, now it is saying:

> FaceBook-Authorize Login Failed: The Server failed to communicate Try Again

which leads me to believe that the key is correct but now there is some type of communication error? I've also inputed the **(wrong key hash/no key hash)** into the facebook mobile settings key hash and will get

> ("invalid-key")

But when doing it the way I just explained above it outputs

> "Login Failed... etc"

I've also uninstalled my facebook each and everytime as there has been issues with facebook not allowing this to work. I've ran this on my dell streak, android one and samsung galaxy tab and get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through all this. Summary:

1 Do what it says at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

2 You should have Cygwin installed and OpenSSL. You can install OpenSSL with Cygwin by selecting the OpenSSL option in the Cygwin installation

3 In Cygwin run:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

-- without newline characters. You can copy it from here.

4 So far you have generated the hash for the standard Android debug key. With this the Facebook example app will run in the emulator (at least it does for me)

5 If you want to use a production key you should do 3 again for the production key, add the new hash to your FB app in the developer area (see 1), sign the .apk and load it to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur due to following reason found of Facebook sdk for android link:

1) Use a signed build. You can sign with a debug key, but make sure that the key you used to sign matches the Key Hash field in the Facebook developer settings.

[link here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/#readme)

Comment: it's the same key hash that I get from Cygwin win I use the keytool and I've inputed it in the developers settings. I've tried the example and it says the same things

Comment: I did the example that you mentioned on my galaxy tab and it works but for my dell streak not so much it still says the same thing... so I know for sure my key hash is good since it's working on the galaxy tab I'm wondering why it's faling to communicate with my dell streak...

Comment: Happen with me too, works in one device, but fails in other.. later on checked with other device and started working, so could not replicate the problem yet, i guess is there any issue with network provider

Comment: I'm guessing that it is a network provider issue but shouldn't be. Due to the fact that I'm able to run the Example app on my galaxy tab on wifi only and on my dell streak I have ran it on wifi and my network data provider and still show's "login failure"... I've even checked the facebook versions and both devices have the same. But I have noticed that it does go to the webview and dispaly page not found 404 really quick before going to the layout...

Comment: Yes i guess same, or there could be something like this, if there is network connection, but still no response from facebook server for connection, there could be sockettimeout exception, which is not handle on client side. hence could result in such error

Answer (score 0):

When you used the debug key I suppose it was working correctly. After you signed the code with a private key, make sure that you use the same key to generate the key hash for the facebook otherwise this problem will occur. Try like this:

1. First you signed the code with and get the key.
2. Second use that key to generate the key hash: keytool -exportcert -alias "Name of the key" -keystore "key store name" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
3. After that enter the password you have given to the key.
4. Get the keyhash value and enter it to your facebook as the new keyhash and save it.
5. open the signed application and try the facebook once again. I hope it will work.

Comment: Yes i'm using the same key debug.keystore when i sign the application I've tried it with a private key as well and I still get failed login.. etc. I believe it's not my key because even without inserting a key hash it will say "invalid_key" but after inserting the way I previously stated it will say failed login: faliure to communicate with server pleast try again later.

Comment: I'm also using the same alias I use when signing the key I not sure why I can't communicate with their server...

Comment: I've also put in the appropiate App Id as well I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this

Comment: I've also notice now that it pulls up the webview and show's the page not found 404 for a quick second and then goes to main layout